# Route Split for OS X

Tags: routing, static-routes, osx-snow-leopard

Hey guys. I'm attempting to install a static route for a Mac Pro desktop.  I'm using Route Split 1.4, which creates a startup script called /etc/routes.sh (The SH script does actually wait for the interface to come online before applying its changes).  However, after i reboot, I lose the static route I entered.  Here's what I get in the /var/log/system.log:

```
-Mac-Pro syslog[70]: routes.sh: Starting RouteSplit
-Mac-Pro /System/Library/CoreServices/loginwindow.app/Contents/MacOS/loginwindow[51]: Login Window Application Started
-Mac-Pro syslog[75]: routes.sh: static route xxx.xx.x.x/xx xxx.xx.x.x
-Mac-Pro net.routes.static[66]: route: writing to routing socket: Network is unreachable
-Mac-Pro net.routes.static[66]: add net xxx.xx.x.x: gateway xxx.xx.x.x: Network is unreachable
```

...Any ideas/suggestions..?

Answer (score 0):

nevermind..found a great alternative for this issue.  The app is called "staticrouted"

Comment: Do you have a link to this app? Cant find it using google...

Comment: For the person asking for the "static route" utility, here is the link: http://alastairs-place.net/projects/staticroute/